# Export Datatable in a Excel file with ajax jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, excel

Hello here my code of my controller action:

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    FILL DataTable

    try
    {
    FileExcel(dt);
    return Json(new { successCode = "1" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { successCode = "0" });
    }
}

public void FileExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();

    HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Ricerca.xls");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    context.Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    context.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    context.Response.Flush();
    htw.Close();
    sw.Close();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

My Ajax Jquery function

```
function ExportExcel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/ExportExcel/',    
        beforeSend: function () {
            AjaxStart('...Export');
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 AjaxStop();
                 alert('success')
        },
        error: function (failure) {
            alert('error');               
        }
    });
}
```

if i call ajax function ExportExcel() through a simple link as

```
<a href="#" onclick="ExportExcel();">Export Excel Ajax</a>
```

it doesn't works !!!!!!

while if use a simple controller action as

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export Excel", "ExportExcel", "Home")
```

the excel file to save appears! i would like use first method (ajax) to manage the esporting delay

Answer (score 1):

ajax does not work this way . You have the excel file's data available in the data variable in the success function but you won't be able to save it as a file . try adding this line to the success function and see for you self :

```
alert(data);
```

you might be able to achieve what you want through an iframe with 0 width and height.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to trigger the download via JavaScript, try the answer from this question [How to export to excel in Asp.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14317105/879818).

```
function ExportExcel() {
    window.open('/Home/ExportExcel/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the Tabletools flash swf file through cdn provides the ability to save pdf files. We will be using Population table. please go through this website

http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-export-jQuery-datatables-to-MS-excel-in-asp-net-MVC/1192#.VzCATYR97IU